# Equivalence of find_if and bind2nd to lower_bound, upper_bound

Tags: c++

I'm tasked with removing `bind2nd` from some code.

I have a sorted (ascending, with possible duplicates) `vector<double> m_x` say, and a value `x` which is a `double` type.

Are

1. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), std::bind2nd(std::greater<double>(), x));`
2. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), std::bind2nd(std::greater_equal<double>(), x));`
3. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), std::bind2nd(std::less<double>(), x)).base();`
4. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), std::bind2nd(std::less_equal<double>(), x)).base();`

Equivalent to

1. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::upper_bound(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), x);`
2. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::lower_bound(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), x);`
3. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::upper_bound(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), x).base();`
4. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::lower_bound(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), x).base();`

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this out with some examples to see what happens?

Comment: @cigien: im sure about (1) and have tested well, (2) quite sure. Don't know about 3 and 4.

Comment: What criteria your vector sorted in each case? Is it sorted in `std::bind2nd()` cases?

Comment: Why don't you test those as well?

Comment: @slava it's sorted so the lowest number is first. But the vector can contain duplicates and the one i pick in the case of a duplicate does matter.

Comment: @cigien: i try to but I'm worried I might not have tested all possibilities

Comment: They always sorted in ascending order? And for `std::bind2nd` too?

Comment: Yes they are always sorted in ascending order, although there could be duplicates.

Comment: My boss also said the find_if was not efficient because of this

Comment: If your vector is sorted in both cases then `find_if()` definitely could be less efficient than binary search.

Comment: If vector is sorted in ascending order then case 3 and 4 for `std::find_if` does not make any sense. It will always return either first element or `end()`. So please provide this information clear way, is it always sorted in ascending order even for cases with `std::find_if()`. Or is `rbegin()` and `rend()` used there as well?

Comment: @slava: I am sorry but I had a mistake in the question. (3) and (4) are rbegin() and rend() in the first version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are
>
> 1. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), std::bind2nd(std::greater<double>(), x));`
> 2. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), std::bind2nd(std::greater_equal<double>(), x));`
>
> Equivalent to
>
> 1. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::upper_bound(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), x);`
> 2. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::lower_bound(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), x);`

Yes. They give the same answer, with fewer comparisons.

> Are
>
> 3. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), std::bind2nd(std::less<double>(), x)).base();`
> 4. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), std::bind2nd(std::less_equal<double>(), x)).base();`
>
> Equivalent to
>
> 3. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::upper_bound(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), x).base();`
> 4. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::lower_bound(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), x).base();`

No. These have undefined behaviour. You need to give them the opposite comparison.

3. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::upper_bound(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), x, std::greater<double>{}).base();`
4. `std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = std::lower_bound(m_x.rbegin(), m_x.rend(), x, std::greater<double>{}).base();`

Answer (score 0):

```
[x](auto&& y) { return std::less_equal<double>{}(y, x); }
```

This a nearly 1:1 replacement.  Odds are you can do better:

```
[&](auto&& y) { return y<=x; }
```

this is probably closer to what the person writing the code meant, but it can have some very subtle differences if the types of the container and/or `x` are not `double`.

---

As for your question, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are defined in terms of `<`.  `<` behaves differently than `!>=` for `NaN`.

So with `NaN` your code isn't going to behave the same.

So they are not equivalent.

---

Assume we eliminate `NaN` from consideration.

The first thing to do is to think of the `equal_range` case, because `equal_range` is far easier to think about than upper/lower bound.

`upper_bound` is the end of the half-open interval where `x` would be inserted.  `lower_bound` is the start of it.

So if `x` is beyond the end of the container, both return `.end()`.

If `x` is before the container, both return `.begin()`.

If one or more copies of `x` are in the container, then `lower_bound` returns an iterator to the first instance of `x`, and `upper_bound` returns the first iterator **after** the last instance of `x`.

If `x` isn't in the container but is between two elements, `a` and `b`, then both upper and lower bound return an iterator referring to `b`.

---

Now we compare.

1 and 2 are the same in both cases.

3 and 4 are not valid C++ code.

So no, they are not equivalent.

Comment: "This a nearly 1:1 replacement. " this is not what OP asks.

Comment: They are sorted. And there are no nan. If they had nan then i think they couldn't be sorted?

Comment: Why 3 and 4 are not valid?

Comment: @SasidiranSangamanautram you should renumber them. For example 1a vs 1b etc. In this way it is very confusing.